# ActiveMQ actively check connection for server liveliness

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way to check an ActiveMQ server is still up, without actually receiving or sending or doing a transaction? I am employing a *"Best Effort 1 Phase Commit"* logic - i.e. not using XA, but instead commit db right before committing the JMS, assuming that the JMS commit will go through unless the server has gone down (as opposed to the SQL commit, which can fail due to e.g. constraint violations).

This is very close to perfectly good enough. However, if I could, right before committing the database transaction, check whether the ActiveMQ server actually was running right now, I would tighten the potential crash-window just a tad bit more.

A way to send some kind of "ping" through the connection would be exactly what I was looking for, e.g. get hold of some kind of status from the actual server (not just ask the connection object whether *it believes* it has a connection to the server). For a SQL Server, "SELECT 1" is pretty nice for this scenario. I guess I could send a message to a topic without any consumers, but this seems a bit heavy handed. It would be no problem to employ methods on the actual ActiveMQConnection object (as opposed to purely the JMS API).

Comment: Do you have to use either the JMS API or the JMS implementation object (e.g. ActiveMQConnection) or can you use a raw Java Socket?

Comment: (Strange, I thought I had answered this) @JustinBertram: I guess I can use a raw socket - however, what I really wonder, is whether "the current connection that I am holding in my hand", the one that I am going to do the actual commit on, is currently still connected to a server which works. The rationale is that if I do that right before I commit the db commit - and then commit the JMS connection - I'll tighten the window for potential crashes in the "Best Effort 1PC" setup.

Comment: I believe I understand your requirement. You're looking for some kind of lightweight replacement for an XA `prepare`. I know that there's nothing in the JMS API which provides what you're looking for. I'm also not aware of anything on the ActiveMQ JMS implementation that would do this either.

Comment: @JustinBertram You are entirely correct in your understanding..! I was hoping for some way to "ping" the server, just to see whether it is up, i.e. very similar to a "SELECT 1" over a SQL Connection. One should think that the ActiveMQ client had some needs for housekeeping chores, that I could hijack for such a lightweight "prepare" logic. Btw: What about the ActiveMQ XA connection? That would at least have to do an actual prepare? Hijack that, without firing up the entire XA machinery?

Comment: Another probably crap way could be to have another JMS Session open over the same connection, and actually send a message to some "/dev/null" sink (i.e. to a topic w/o any listeners). If this goes through w/o problems, the connection is most probably clean.